# CSS Transition doesn't work on inactive browser tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have an element with CSS Transition. When `element.style.left` changes in an inactive tab, the animation starts only when I switch back to the tab.

Here is a code sample

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

```
#box {
  top: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```
const box = document.getElementById("box");

let flag = true;

function move() {
  if (flag) {
    box.style.left = "800px";
  } else {
    box.style.left = "0";
  }
  flag = !flag;
}

function onVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.hidden) {
    console.log(Date.now(), "hide");
    move();
    console.log(Date.now(), "moved");
  } else {
    console.log(Date.now(), "show");
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChange);
box.addEventListener("transitionstart", () => console.log(Date.now(), "transitionstart"));
box.addEventListener("transitionend", () => console.log(Date.now(), "transitionend" ));
```

Console log:

```
1669760420590, "hide"
1669760420590, "moved"
1669760423272, "show"
1669760423273, "transitionstart"
1669760425264, "transitionend"
```

Same code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ihor0k/8xkqum9L/

How can I make the animation to start at the moment when the tab becomes inactive? Or at least I need some workaround to change animation progress to 100% when I switch back to the tab.

I know that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are throttled in inactive tab, but I cannot find any info about throttling of CSS Transitions.

Comment: It's probably also throttled, to save battery power the browser doesn't render animations that aren't visible.

Comment: But shouldn't browser just move the box without animation then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. I cancel the animation if  it should already have ended when `transitionstart` event happens. So I still see the full animation if I switch back to the tab within 2 seconds. But if I switch later, the box will be in the final position.

```
let transitionEndAt = Date.now();
const transitionDuration = 2000;

function move() {
  transitionEndAt = Date.now() + transitionDuration;
  ...
}

box.addEventListener("transitionstart", onTransitionStart);

function onTransitionStart() {
  if (transitionEndAt < Date.now()) {
    box.style.transition = "none";
    setTimeout(() => box.style.transition = "", 0);
  };
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Ihor0k/7wf3pund/

I would really appreciate if someone provides better solution.